# Using puppeteer, how can i wait for specific xhr request to be complete

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I'm testing my react app and I want to check if XHR request from my app is sent. When I use page.waitFor(5000), it will sometimes work but sometimes not. Is there a better way to make the code wait for XHR to be complete or to be resolved?

Comment: Why don't you try javascript promises https://javascript.info/promise-basics

Comment: Maybe [`page.waitForResponse()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options) can help?

Comment: If a specific `DOM` change happens after request has been finished you could use `page.waitForSelector('.class-of-element-showed-after-req-complete')`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to change your strategy. Instead of waiting for X seconds - trigger an event that satisfy your needs.

Because you test your own application I will suggest listening to your network traffic (following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941601/how-to-inspect-network-traffic-and-get-the-url-of-resource-requests))

In short:

- Enable traffic inspection `page.setRequestInterceptionEnabled` set to `true`
- Register an event listener for each request `page.on('request'`
- Check (for every request) if it matches your desirable request (using the `request.url` property)
- Call your function when the url matches the desirable request