# How to get a list of network requests from the URL in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, networking, network-monitoring

I'm building an app with react-native and I would like to know if there is some way to get a list of network requests from the URL (not for debugging) for doing with them some process after that...

[image]

I tried to search but I just saw solutions for web app.

[1#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941601/how-to-inspect-network-traffic-and-get-the-url-of-resource-requests)

[2#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621084/how-to-get-list-of-network-requests-done-by-html)

Comment: Have you tried Flipper? It has a network watcher feature.

Comment: @FreakyCoder  I know but i want to get the data of the network requests and keep it for some use..
and flipper it's just for debugging.

Comment: Oh I see, you want to watch & do some stuff with the network URLs. I will research about it :)

Comment: @ FreakyCoder Thank you :)